# Jquery UI autocomplete with Accent-map and Multiple values at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

What must I change on the code?

This is the code for Multiple values

```
<script>
    $( "#tags" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

And this is the code for Accent maps..

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#developer" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
            response( $.grep( names, function( value ) {
                value = value.label || value.value || value;
                return matcher.test( value ) || matcher.test( normalize( value ) );
            }) );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I would like to make an autocomplete that does the accents and the multiple values as well.

Comment: can u paste u r code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have no idea how to begin. I have the example codes and I don't know what to do from here. Can you do two functions in the autocomplete source?

Comment: see this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4-BsBoNr9E